# ausstatten / ausrüsten / versehen

Tags: synonym

Es gibt einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen "ausstatten", "ausrüsten" und "versehen", wenn sie "to equip" bedeuten? Wenn ich mir die Definitionen und Beispiele von Duden ansehe, sehe ich keine.

Beispiel:
   Ich rüste / statte / versehe die Gruppe für die Reise mit Proviant (aus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vielen Situationen mögen die Verben *austatten*, *ausrüsten* und *versehen* synonym verwendet werden. Dennoch gibt es Unterschiede bei der Betonung bestimmter Aspekte.

#### Ausstatten

Das Verb *ausstatten* verwendet man in der Regel dort, wo abstrakte Werte wie Qualität, Komfort, Ertrag, Rechte und Ähnliches erhöht werden. Beispiele:

> - Das Haus ist mit einem Pool und einer Sauna ausgestattet.
> - Die Wohnung ist geräumig und gemütlich ausgestattet.
> - Wir statten das Auto standardmäßig mit Sitzheizung aus.
> - Unser Prokurist ist mit besonderen Rechten ausgestattet.

#### Ausrüsten

Das Verb *ausrüsten* wird dann verwendet, wenn der Zweck der Ausrüstung ist, bestimmte Ereignisse, Vorkommnisse, Engpässe, Schwierigkeiten oder Ähnliches zu überwinden. Es stammt vom Verb *sich rüsten* ab. Beispiele:

> - Der Steg ist mit zwei Schwimmreifen ausgerüstet.
> - Das Fahrzeug ist mit einer Wegfahrsperre ausgerüstet.
> - Haben Sie sich für die Wanderung gut ausgerüstet?
> - Sie werden sich mit Waffen ausrüsten.

#### Versehen

Das Verb *versehen* ist eher neutral, aber gehoben. Gelegentlich wird es statt *haben* oder *besitzen* verwendet. Beispiele:

> - Das Fenster ist mit allerlei Verzierungen versehen.
> - Die Bluse habe ich mit einem neuen Knopf versehen.
> - Die Hose ist ja mit Löchern versehen!
> - Er versah den Brief mit einem roten Siegel.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, das "versehen werden" oder gar "versehen sein" synonym ist zu "haben" oder "besitzen". "Versehen" an sich ist ja gar kein Synonym dazu.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Beispiele mit austatten und "Komfort/Rechten erhöhen". Könntest du bitte ein Beispiel geben, in dem "ausstatten" mit "Ertrag erhöhen" verwandt ist?

Comment: Ein Gegenbeispiel zur der Unterscheidung zwischen aussstatten und ausrüsten: Diese Firma stattet meine Hochzeit aus. Hier gibt es kein Erhöhung von Quälitat/Komfort/Ertrag/Recht.